# PHP ZipArchive large ExtractTo with folders

Tags: php, zip, limit, unzip, php-ziparchive

I'm having an issue with ZipArchive extractTo.

I've a +300Mb ZIP file, with 100 folders and +3k XML files in each. When I start the process, it runs until 20 folders and the inside archives and stops working.

This is my unzip function...

```
public function unzip_files($zipfile, $parent_folder)
{
    ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
    set_time_limit(0);      

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open($zipfile);

    if( $res === true )
    {
        if( $zip->extractTo(HCAT_UPLOADS . $parent_folder) );
        {
            $zip->close();

            print '<strong>'. basename($zipfile) .'</strong> '. __('unziped correctly', self::$ltd) .'.<br />';

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            print __('Failed to unzip', self::$ltd) .' <strong>'. basename($zipfile) .'</strong>.<br />';

            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print __('Failed to unzip', self::$ltd) .' <strong>'. basename($zipfile) .'</strong>.<br />';

        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I unzip all the folders? Any hint? :)

Thanks!
**R**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZipArchive limits ExtractTo to 65535 files and there's no way to do an offset.

So, best workaround found BTW is to use shell commands:

```
public function unzip_files($zipfile, $parent_folder)
{
    $disableds = explode(', ', ini_get('disable_functions'));

    if( !in_array('exec', $disableds) )
    {
        exec("unzip -o $zipfile -x -d $parent_folder");

        print '<strong>'. basename($zipfile) .'</strong> '. __('unziped correctly', self::$ltd) .'.<br />';
    }
}
```

Best!
**R**

Comment: It is not just ExtractTo - PHP 5.3.3 seems to have an internal limit that ZipArchive cannot address more than 65k files.

Answer (score 0):

**It worked for me..!!** because one of our application is running in PHP 5.3 - `extractTo()` which doesn't allow us to upload ZIP files more then 65KB.

`exec("unzip -o $zipFileName -x -d $uploadedPath");`

Example:

```
$zip_obj = new ZipArchive();
$zip_obj_data = $zip_obj->open($zipFileName);
if ($zip_obj_data === true) {
    #$zip_obj->extractTo($uploaded_path);
    #$zip_obj->close();
    $disableds = explode(', ', ini_get('disable_functions'));
    if( !in_array('exec', $disableds) )
    {
        $zipfile = $zipFileName;
        exec("unzip -o $zipfile -x -d $uploaded_path");
    } 
    unlink($zipFileName);

}
```

Note : 'exec' command is not coming under PHP Security group, using this command in your won risk.